# keep div and inner elements in same state / position etc on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple music player built with angular.js I'm looking for a simple JS solution that would simply keep the previous state / position etc of my div `.musicPlayer` and it's inner contents when the page is refreshed in the browser.

I tried the below but it didn't work in my case...

```
<script>
// Before refreshing the page, save the form data to sessionStorage
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("musicBox", $('.musicBox').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("player", $('.player').val());
    sessionStorage.setItem("seekBase", $('.seekBase').val());
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have any method of checking if there's a `sessionStorage` object on reload? In order for the data to persist, you need to have some way of parsing it on reload.

Comment: I tried your code. It worked properly. Refer this - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/j8m8fdsj/